# Android ViewPager skip page animation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager with multiple Fragments.

I would like to skip some of the pages inside it. I have done the logic for it. It looks like this:

```
protected List<Fragment> pages;

public void nextSlide()
{

    int currentItem = getPager().getCurrentItem();
    int pagesCount = mPagerAdapter.getCount();


    while (++currentItem < pagesCount)
    {
        Fragment page = pages.get(currentItem);
        if (page.isEnabled())
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (currentItem < pagesCount)
    {
        getPager().setCurrentItem(currentItem);
    }
}
```

But I have problem with animation between 2 pages (with one or more skipped between that). It 'slides' to the proper page, but the animation skips through all 'disabled' pages.

How to handle that, to remove disabled pages from this animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

there is a `setCurrentItems(int,boolean)` that has the page number and weather to smooth scroll (animate) or not

Comment: but the perfect way which I would like to have animation, but between only 2 enabled pages

Comment: @Tomasz I dont understand what you mean, if you want specific pages to animate and other to not you have to handle the logic

Comment: I mean, I would like to view on Pager only pages, that have `isEnabled() == true`. Right now I have all the pages in my array, and all the pages are logically in my pager. So my question is right now: Is there a way to create adapter, which will not show 'disabled' pages.

Comment: @Tomasz: "Is there a way to create adapter, which will not show 'disabled' pages" -- that is conceivable but could get tricky. You would have to create your own `PagerAdapter` implementation, though -- I would be rather surprised if extending `FragmentPagerAdapter` could somehow support this. As an alternative, you could have an adapter that just has only the active pages, adding and removing pages as needed. [My `ArrayPagerAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager) supports that model.