# android viewpager skip page

Tags: android, xamarin, android-viewpager

I have several pages in viewpager, but want to skip particular one. Is it possible? I have override several methods in my OnPageChangeListener, but can't detect where CurrentItem changes during sliding.
Need to skip special index only when user sliding between pages, here is my code, but it doesn't work

```
        public void OnPageScrollStateChanged (int state)
        {
            if (pager.CurrentItem == 2 && !buttonClicked) {
                if (prevPosition > 2) {
                    pager.SetCurrentItem (1, false);    
                } else {
                    pager.SetCurrentItem (3, false);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097926/android-viewpager-skip-page-animation

Comment: 1. write your logic in onPageSelected() 
2. And then do pager.setCurrentItem()

Comment: It doesn't work too, because OnPageSelected is called after GetItem in adapter, this means that fragment is already initialized and tab is selected

Comment: are you using a tabHost

Comment: nope, viewpager and simple buttons .
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PagerSlidingTabStrip-for-Xamarin.Android/tree/master/PagerSlidingTabStrip